# Ruby on Rails - linking between parent and child - No route matches [POST]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am quite new to rails, and have done some interesting tutorials, however once I've stepped outside of their neat walls, I've hit a problem with implementing parent-child relationships.

I have a rails application that I'm building which has a hierarchy of theme --< category --< level.  I'll ignore level for the moment, as the answer to this question would be applicable there.

Here are the theme and category models.

theme.rb:

```
class Theme < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :categories
end
```

category.rb:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theme
  has_many :levels
end
```

I want to display a table of categories within a theme.  I have added categories inside a do block for the theme in routes.

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :levels
  resources :categories
  resources :themes do
    resources :categories
  end

  root "themes#index"
end
```

I've added a `<%= render :partial => @theme.categories %>` to the theme's show.html.erb file.  The partial file renders a row of the table and I want the name to be displayed as a link to the show page for the category.

_category.html.erb:

```
<%= div_for (category) do %>
  <div class="category_wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="pull-left">
      <div class="category_name">
        <%= link_to category.name, category, method: :show %>
      </div>
      <div class="category_question"><%= category.question %></div>
      <div class="category_description"><%= category.description %></div>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Unfortunately, when I click on the link in the theme's table of categories, I get the aforementioned error - `No route matches [POST] "/themes/1"`.

If I refresh the browser, the page loads fine with the exact same URL.  I figure [POST] is relevant here, but I don't understand what I need to change in the partial file's link or the routes file (or something else?) to resolve!  Any assistance would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `rake routes` on the console? It will show all the routes your app sees, so you can see if you have the specific route that fails.
And also, just in case, make the `root` instruction be the first one in your routes. Order matters there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the ***routes***, your `link_to` should be like below

```
<%= link_to category.name, theme_category_path(category, @theme) %>
```

Make sure you have `@theme = Theme.find(params[:d])` in `themes_controller` `show` method

Comment: Thanks very much, Pavan - that's sorted it!

Answer (score 2):

I have just realized. There is a mistake in your code that I can see.

In your _category.html.erb you have:

`<%= link_to category.name, category, method: :show %>`

It's not method (method defines http methods such as get, post, put, etc). You have to write **action**:

`<%= link_to category.name, category, action: :show %>`

For some reason, Rails was understanding you didn't want GET but POST there.

Comment: Thanks - this is also good information - knowing the distinction between the action and method is useful.